# XCode Organizer Device Console Length

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-organizer

I have an device that was used in the field where errors occurred.  I want to be able read the console logs on the device to determine the error.  Unfortunately it appears that the XCode Organizer will only show a smaller portion of the log file because the log messages from several weeks ago are not appearing.  Is there any other way to access full contents of the log or extend the buffer size in XCode?

Answer (score 0):

Do the backups contain console logs?  Not sure.  You can find them in iTunes->Preferences->Devices

You can always write messages to a log file and print directly to that, they will be there as long as you let them be (buyer beware).